# Contextual Filter not getting the correct NID from URL

Tags: views

I **THINK** my Contextual Filter from my view is not getting the correct NID from my URL.

I have a view page with a path of "node/%/agenda".

The link on my menu is "node/[node:nid]/agenda".

The view page will get the nid from a content type "Venue". 
Example: 
Venue: Rave = NID: 101
View page will be = "node/101/agenda"

I have a working block of "Upcoming Events" and this works perfectly fine on my venue content type. But when I use it on a view page it's not working anymore. Basically this block shows the "Upcoming Events" from "Event" content type that is related to the "Venue" content type.

BLOCK: [image]
Setting: [image]

How it works on content type venue: [image]
This is the wrong part:
[image]

As you can see it does not get the same result on the view page, it does not even show the "No Result". I am calling the correct block.

Am I missing something big? I hope someone can help!

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! ^_^

Comment: You didn't post the settings of the most relevant part of the view, the contextual filter.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it now, posted the setting

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the block is configured to show on that page? Default value Content ID from URL should work unless you have some specific validation rules for the contextual filter that aren't being met.

Comment: Yes, I did not put any other specific validation rules. Just the content ID from URL. If I try to remove the contextual filter then everything will show, if I put it back, it shows the blank div. there's a no result behavior but that's not showing on the page.

Comment: did you tried to connect events with the venue in RELATIONSHIPS ?

Answer (score 0):

According to what i can see from the screen shots, you didn't specify your relationship entity on advanced menu. If I were you, I would pick a entity reference, then i would pick a content contextual filters with Nid. Otherwise there is no way that block is gonna understand what the relationship is. Please update us your work. This is a very sensitive topic of drupal. Kind regards

Answer (score -1):

Block displays have no source of arguments at all; they cannot pull arguments from the URL so Create a content pane instead of block in the view and in the "argument input" add the argument number.

Comment: This is not true. There are ways to use arguments with block views.